# asterisk is not working inside a script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

When I write this line inside my script it does not work it is not able to find any such file there. But through command line it is working. It is happening with every command , `*` is not giving the file name.

```
zgrep  $line2 *.gz  >> CSP_Final_${DATE_TIME}.DAT
```

The error is:

```
 file_loop line2
+ line2=line2
+ zgrep line2 '*.gz'
+ 1>> CSP_Final_20120926_221841.DAT
gzip: *.gz: No such file or directory
```

code :

```
while read line
    do

if [[ ${profile_count} -gt 700 ]]
                           then
                                DATE_TIME=`date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`
                                export profile_count=1
                                sleep 1
                           fi
        profile_count=`expr ${profile_count} + 1`
 count=`expr ${count} + 1`
echo " ${count} \t"
echo "${profile_count} \t"
echo $line1
#export line2=`echo ${line}`

file_loop line2
done<abhi


file_loop()
{
line2=$1
#while read line1
#do
#echo $line1
echo $PWD
zgrep  $line2 *.gz  >> CSP_Final_${DATE_TIME}.DAT
#done<abhi2
}
```

Comment: Something else is happening. Show the actual code.

Comment: Your script must not run in the directory where you store your `*.gz` files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following immediately before your `zgrep` line:

```
echo "zgrep $line2 *.gz"
```

What do you get for output?

Also, try replacing the wildcard expression with the equivalent `find` command and see if the behavior changes:

```
zgrep $line2 $(find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.gz')
```

What does your shebang line look like for this script?  What shell are you using when you try the command on the command line?

**Update:**
I see that you are using `#!/bin/ksh -xvf` as a shebang line.  If I'm remembering correctly, the `-f` option disables filename globbing.  This would explain the behavior that you are seeing.  Since your interactive shell doesn't have this option set, the code works there.  Try removing the `-f` option and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: /abppkg7glb1/u2u/aimsys/abpwrk38/CSP
+ echo 'zgrep line2 *.gz'
zgrep line2 *.gz
+ zgrep line2 '*.gz'
+ 1>> CSP_Final_20120927_120220.DAT
gzip: *.gz: No such file or directory

Comment: Shebang :#!/bin/ksh  -xvf
Shell :echo $SHELL
-e /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: ON the command line it is working fine , with *.gz it is able to feed all the files to the zgrep command

Comment: With the command you have provided it is like :zgrep line2 *.gz
zgrep $line2 $(find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.gz')+ find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.gz'
+ zgrep line2 ./MY201208065072.gz ./MY201208045009.gz ./MY201207284792.gz ./MY201208024937.gz

Comment: @Kimi- I think the problem may be in your shebang line (see my update above for details).